# rational roots theorem takes too long

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When I try to solve

> $$2x^7 - x^4 + 4x^3 -5 = 0 $$

The rational roots theorem does not come in handy because you must raise the potential roots to the 7th power.

Is there is a faster way to approach this, without using a calculator, because my teacher would want me to do this by hand in 1 minute.

The official question states:

Prove the equation has at least four imaginary roots

Comment: After getting 1 as a root, it is still too complex

Comment: I'm assuming you mean complex roots, since this isn't true otherwise.

Comment: The question specifically states " at least four imaginary roots", why wouldn't it be true otherwise?

Comment: Because there aren't $4$ imaginary roots? Unless your definition of imaginary differs from mine.

Comment: "imaginary roots"${}\neq{}$"complex roots".

Comment: "Because there aren't 4 imaginary roots?" - How did you determine this?

Comment: @Pythagoras OP already knows that...

Comment: The rational root theorem does not address whether roots are real or complex, so is not the proper tool for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), this polynomial has no negative real roots.  By inspection, it does not have zero as a root.  By Descartes' rule of signs, it has one or three positive real roots.

Since it has seven roots (counting multiplicity) and at most three of them are real, at least four of them are complex.

But say we wanted to be more precise than the question demands...

The rational roots theorem suggests checking $  \pm 5$, $\pm 5/2$, $\pm 1$, and $\pm 1/2$, but we can reject all the negative candidates by the first observation in the previous paragraph.  I would try these in $1$, $1/2$, $5$, and $5/2$ order since this is roughly in order of increasing complication.  But looking at all four...  (It helps to have practiced estimating and approximating quantities many, many times.)

- Trying $1/2$, the three terms with $x$s are $<1$, so theis sum cannot possibly be as large as $3$, much less $5$, so $1/2$ is not a root.
- Trying $1$, we find a root.  Continue after this list finishes.
- Trying $5/2$, we have terms $-5$, $4 \frac{8}{125} \approx 1/4$ by comparing the "$3$" in $32$ with the "$12$" in $125$, $-625 / 16 \approx -40$ because $16 \cdot 4 = 64$ is close to $62.5$, and $2 5^7/2^7 > 256$ because $5/2>2$.  There's no way the little terms can cancel the big term.
- Trying $5$: $2 \cdot 5^7 = 2 \cdot 5^4 5^3 = 2(625)(125) > 120\,000$ and the other terms cannot possibly cancel this.

So we found the one rational root.  Factoring it out of the given polynomial (using [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) or [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division)), we obtain
$$  2x^6 + 2x^5 + 2x^4 + x^3 + 5x^2 + 5x + 5 \text{.}  $$
We already know this has no negative or zero roots.  By Descartes' rule of signs, it has no positive roots.  Therefore, all six roots of this polynomial are complex.

This means that the original polynomial has one real root (at $x = 1$) and six complex roots.

Answer (score 2):

You already observed that $1$ is a root: this is crucial, since we can use long division to divide the polynomial by $x-1$.

Hence, we get $$g(x)=\frac{2x^7-x^4+4x^3-5}{x-1}=2x^6+2x^5+2x^4+x^3+5x^2+5x+5=(2x^4+5)(x^2+x+1)+x^3$$

Note that $x^2+x+1>0$, since when $x<0$, $x^2+x+1>x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$.

Moreover, when $x\leq-1$ or $x\geq0$, $x^2+x+1>1$, so $g(x)>0$ since $|2x^4+5|>|x^3|$.

So, the only place where a root is possible is $-1<x<0$. However, note that here, $(2x^4+5)\cdot(x^2+x+1)\geq3$, so we are done.

Comment: how were you able to factor into: >$$(2^4+5)(^2++1)+^3$$

Comment: @BobSmith Look at the first three terms, and factor out $2x^4$. Look at the last $3$, and factor out $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the OP meant to say complex roots, not imaginary roots (otherwise there has to be a factor of the form $x^2+a^2$ for some real number $a$, but this can be easily dismissed).  Note that $$\frac{2x^7 - x^4 + 4x^3 -5}{x-1}=2\left(x^3+\frac{x^2}2\right)^2+\frac32\left(x^2+\frac{x}{3}\right)^2+\frac{29}6\left(x+\frac{15}{29}\right)^2+\frac{215}{58},$$
or note that
$$\frac{2x^7 - x^4 + 4x^3 -5}{x-1}=2\left(x^3+\frac{x^2}2\right)^2+\frac32\left(x^2+\frac{x}{3}\right)^2+\frac{43}{12}x^2+5\left(\frac{x}{2}+1\right)^2.$$
So $2x^7-x^4+4x^3-5$ has only one real root $x=1$.

Comment: I don't understand how you broke up the polynomial,

Comment: This is the standard "completing the square" trick.  You first try to get rid of $x^6$ and $x^5$ with $2(x^3+x^2/2)^2$, then remove $x^4$ and $x^3$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The function $$f(x) = 2x^7 - x^4 + 4x^3 -5$$ is strictly increasing thus it has only one real root which is $x=1$

Note that $$f'(x) = 2x^2(7x^4-2x+6)$$ is always positive.

$$ 7x^4+6>2x $$ is evident.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $P(x)$ the polynomial.

By Descartes' rule of signs,  $P(x)$ has three roots with positive real part.

$P(-x)=-2x^7-x^4-4x^3-5$ has all non-zero coefficients with the same sign, therefore by the mentioned rule, $P(x)$ doesn't have a root with negative real part.

Consequently,  four roots are imaginary.